# AngularJS ng-show , ng-hide

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have an AgularJS search using a filter, which works. I now want the filter to only show results that match the filter.

So, I want the initial data load to not show, if my typed in filter matches, then show the results.

Here is my code so far:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <div ng-app>
      <div ng-controller="CashTransController">      
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">

        <br />

        <div><strong>Filter Results</strong></div>

        <br />

        <div class="row"></div>

        <br/>

        <table border="0" class="items">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Purchaser</th>
              <th>Redemption Code</th>
              <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
              <td>{{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}</td>
              <td valign="top"><h3>{{item.redemption_code}}</h3></td>
              <td><h3><a href="#">{{item.creation_date}}</a></h3></td>    
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply add a [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to the table items.

I don't know why you called your search model search.$ and not just search.

Try this code. It will only show the results if you typed something into the input:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search">
        <br/>

        <div><strong>Filter Results</strong></div>
        <br/>

        <div class="row">
            <p>{{search}}</p>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <table border="0" class="items">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Purchaser</th>
                <th>Redemption Code</th>

                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-show="search" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
                <td>{{item.firstname}} {{item.lastname}}</td>
                <td valign="top"><h3>{{item.redemption_code}}</h3></td>
                <td><h3><a href="#">{{item.creation_date}}</a></h3></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works, but after the search is done, and you delete the filter text, the entire list is visible, which is what I don't want.

Comment: Thats the reason why you have to use ng-model="search" instead of ng-model="search.$". Then it should work it when you delete the filter text.

Comment: Gotcha! It works. I think search.$ is remnant from a previous version of angularJS.

Comment: How do I Accept your response as the answer? Do I use the 'Answer Your Question' button?

Comment: you have to click the ✓ Icon under the count number